# using ' ' replace " " when i use the setAttributeNS in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to add this attribute and this value with javascript :

```
routerLink='/panel/country/add'
```

but when I set attribute in javascript:

```
    let Link: string = "routerLink";
    tailDiv.setAttributeNS(null, Link, this.subItems[i].route)
```

it use the " " but i need ' ' in this `"/panel/country/add"` but i need this `'/panel/country/add'`

how can I do this?

Comment: `let Link: string = "routerLink";` is **not** javascript

Comment: `"'/panel/country/add'"` ?